# When trying to ping and get records of dns domain, I get unexplained error

Tags: go, dns, ping

I am very new to golang, and I am using the dns library from github.com/miekg/dns to do this. I'm just trying the library out. I first call upon google.com in a loop which calls the domain 10 times, then averages the 10 pings. It does this with the defined client IP being localhost on port 53.

When I do this out of the loop however, with my client IP being the same localhost on port 53, it gives the error of "connection refused". Same thing happens when I set my client IP to be 192.168.1.21, which has the same value of localhost. HOWEVER, when I set my client IP to be 192.168.1.32, which is the IP of my raspberry pi on my network, it works! How come it is able to make the DNS connection in that loop, but not outside the loop? How come it is able to make the connection outside the loop with a IP different from the device I am running the script on? Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/miekg/dns"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    m := new(dns.Msg)
    m.SetQuestion(dns.Fqdn("google.com"), dns.TypeA)

    c := new(dns.Client)
    var individualPings float64


    //looping over for 10 times and prints each one while also adding it to variable individualPings to get average at the end
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        _, rtt, _ := c.Exchange(m, "localhost:53")
        fmt.Printf("%vth ping is %v\n", i, rtt)
        individualPings = individualPings + (float64(rtt))
    }

    pingAverage := individualPings / 10
    fmt.Print("\nThe ping average was: ", math.Round(pingAverage)/1000, "ms\n")

    //tries to do the same thing
    _, rtt, err := c.Exchange(m, "localhost:53")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    print(rtt)


    //tries to do the same thing but client is defined with it's ipv4 instead of just "localhost"
    in, rtt, err := c.Exchange(m, "192.168.1.21:53")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(in.Answer)
    fmt.Println(rtt, "\n\n")

        
        //tries to do the same thing but client is defined to be my raspberry pi instead of the device the script is running on. This works. Of course the program panics before it reaches this part, however I've tested it without the clutter above and it works
    in, rtt, err = c.Exchange(m, "192.168.1.32:53")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for record := range in.Answer {
        fmt.Println(in.Answer[record])
        fmt.Print("\t", rtt)
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

======================================

Answer (score 2):

First, in order to do a DNS query on a specific IP and port there need to be actually a DNS server running there and responding to queries. There is no guarantee that such a DNS server is on `localhost:53` or `192.168.1.21:53`. So first check with tools like [dig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_(command)) that you actually do get a response from a DNS server at a specific ip:port in the first place before asking why you get errors in your program.

> I first call upon google.com in a loop which calls the domain 10 times, then averages the 10 pings. It does this with the defined client IP being localhost on port 53.
> When I do this out of the loop however, with my client IP being the same localhost on port 53, it gives the error of "connection refused".

It likely gives the same error inside the loop. Only, inside the loop you simply don't handle the error and thus nothing gets reported. Compare your code inside the loop (no error handling):

```
    _, rtt, _ := c.Exchange(m, "localhost:53")
```

with the code outside the loop (with error handling)

```
_, rtt, err := c.Exchange(m, "localhost:53")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, because my raspberry pi is running as a DNS server, explaining why it works on it. However, inside the loop, with my client IP being the device I'm running the script on, it still works, and it sends the 10 pings. Wierd....

Comment: Also one thing. When I used localhost, and ignore the error, everything worked fine and I didn't seem to see any issue. I know it's not best practice, but what If I ignore the error? If I don't, what am I supposed to put as the client IP? When I put it to be my raspberry pi's it returns weird numbers that don't make sense like 6.303333ms(I usually get around 28ms). I'm new to coding networking and server side things with golang, but It's something I REALLY enjoy. Any resources to learn? Thanks :)

Comment: @RadinKhosraviani: *"what am I supposed to put as the client IP?"*  - you don't put any __client__ IP at all. If you want to make a DNS query you have to put in the IP and port of the DNS __server__ - of course there must actually be such a server. If you want to do something else (like just get RTT to the system) - then trying to do this using a DNS library might be the wrong approach in the first place. An 6ms is perfectly fine as RTT in your local network, 28ms is more normal for internet. Note that by measuring a DNS query you don't measure the RTT to the looked up domain.